# Specify output directory for MATLAB crash dump files

Tags: linux, matlab

I am running MATLAB on Linux with limited storage space in my home directory (`/home/$USER`). When MATLAB crashes, it places the crash dump files (`matlab_crash_dump.XXXX`) in my home directory. I would like to change the directory in which these files are placed. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Which version of matlab, which linux repository?

Comment: matlab version : matlab/R2013a
Linux is : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11, linux repo is any other than /home/$USER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `MATLAB_LOG_DIR` environment variable. MATLAB will use this to store all crash dumps.

From a [related MATLAB Central discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/24507):

> If you have set the environment variable $MATLAB_LOG_DIR, that's where
>   we'll write the crash dump file. Otherwise, look in $HOME on UNIX, or
>   in $TEMP, $TMP, $WINDIR, and finally C:\ (in that order) on Windows.
>   The file will be named "matlab_crash_dump.$pid" where $pid is the
>   process ID of MATLAB.

You can either do this within your `.bashrc` file

```
export MATLAB_LOG_DIR=/custom/dir
```

Or within MATLAB itself prior to running any commands (or within your [`matlabrc` file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabrc.html))

```
setenv('MATLAB_LOG_DIR', '/custom/dir')
```

If you need to test this, the following simple mex file will cause a crash resulting in a crash dump file.

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    /* Access beyond the length of prhs */
    size_t x = mxGetM(prhs[6]);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, One question: Do I have to initialize the 'MATLAB_LOG_DIR' environment variable or is it pre defined in the library and I can use it directly in 'matlabrc' - setenv('MATLAB_LOG_DIR', '/custom/dir') ??

Comment: @Pratul it is not defined initially and it will use your home directory if it is not defined. If it is defined them it will use that instead.

Comment: Definitely, Just setting up everything to give it a try.